# coredata custom migration by detecting version

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to do a custom coredata migration.

In the old datamodel, I have a Contacts table with a status Field. 
Now, I wish to create another table - "Recommends" for every record in the the contacts table if the status == 2. The attributes in the Recommends table is totally different from that of the Contacts table.

What would be a good way to do this.

From what I read, it seems that I should use a custom coredata migration policy and override

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject*)src ¬
entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping*)map manager:(NSMigrationManager*)mgr error:(NSError**)error
```

But it seems too complicated to achieve what I want to do. Currently I have now at version 15 of my datamodel. Do I need to create the mapping models for all previous model versions from 1 to 14? If I have version 20 next time and a user directly updates from version 10 to version 20, does it trigger this migration policy also? It is very hard to test what will happen if anything goes wrong.

I tried another method - When I initialize the storecoordinator, I use:

```
    NSManagedObjectModel *destinationModel = [self managedObjectModel];
    // Migration is needed if destinationModel is NOT compatible
    BOOL isMigrationNeeded = ![destinationModel isConfiguration:nil
                                    compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];

    if (isMigrationNeeded) {

        self.needMigration = YES;
        DDLogInfo(@"Migration needed");

        NSArray* sourceVersionIdentifiers = [sourceMetadata objectForKey:NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiersKey];
        self.sourceMigrationVersion = [sourceVersionIdentifiers lastObject];
        DDLogInfo(@"Source Version:%@",self.sourceMigrationVersion);

        NSSet* destVersionIdentifiers = [destinationModel versionIdentifiers];
        self.destMigrationVersion = [destVersionIdentifiers anyObject];
        DDLogInfo(@"Destination Version:%@",self.destMigrationVersion);
    }

- (NSDictionary *)sourceMetadata:(NSError **)error
{
    return [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                      URL:[self storeURL]
                                                                    error:error];
}
```

Basically, I try to compare the datamodel version of the old model and the new model and run some custom code somewhere else If I detect that it is migrating over a certain version.

The problem is that some of my older datamodel versions do not have version identifiers. Even if I add them now, it will not show in the source metadata. I am guessing that you have to set it explicitly when the store is being created from the model?

Another alternative is to ignore all of the above and set and save a flag when the migration has been performed and check the flag everytime on launch. But that does not sound very clean to me.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also user a simple `NSUserDefault`. It will also not be present in older versions. This is a perfectly acceptable mechanism and not "unclean" in any way.

Yes, you will need all your versions of the data model starting from the first one, and yes, the migration from 10 to 20 will be automatic, provided you enabled automatic migration in your persistent store.